# Hiding one td and collapse other td in row for not showing space between the tds (auto merge)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Code snippet:

```
<TD><center>
<asp:ImageButton id=imgManagOrd Runat="server" ImageUrl="images/ManageOrders.jpg"></asp:ImageButton></center></TD>
<TD><center>
<asp:ImageButton id=imgStockOrder Runat="server" ImageUrl="images/stockorder.jpg">    </asp:ImageButton></center></TD>
<TD><center>
<asp:ImageButton id=imgAdmin Runat="server" ImageUrl="images/admin.jpg">    </asp:ImageButton></center></TD>
<TD><center>
<asp:ImageButton id=imgContact Runat="server" ImageUrl="images/contact.jpg">    </asp:ImageButton></center></TD>
```

I am hiding specific td from codebehind depending upon the permission and I have not specify the width of these tds respectivly.

so as a result there are odd spaces between final tds.
Please find the images :
**All tds:**
[image: All tds]

**Few Td hidden:**
[image: few td hidden]

Please tell how can i align resulted tds in a row without showing the spaces between.

Comment: somehow, i cannot see your images, may be others aswell. so try bringing your images here itself(yes you can paste an image in your question). also, try adding a class `.hide{display:none;}`. to your td from codebehind to hide them.

Comment: thanx Manish . i have uploaded images again

Comment: so how do you hide your tds from codebehind? just the oneliner action code will do

Comment: Just hiding with the imageButton id : id.visible = false. but all other tds are not merging. i have not specified any width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a markup like this:

```
<tr>
<td><imagebutton id="img1">..</imagebutton></td>
<td><imagebutton id="img2">..</imagebutton></td>
<td><imagebutton id="img3">..</imagebutton></td>
<td><imagebutton id="img4">..</imagebutton></td>
<tr>
```

and you hide one of the `imagebuttons` from the codebehind. i.e.

```
   img2.Visible=false
```

so it produces a markup like this:(say you hide the 2nd imagebutton)

```
<tr>
<td><imagebutton id="img1">..</imagebutton></td>
<td></td>
<td><imagebutton id="img3">..</imagebutton></td>
<td><imagebutton id="img4">..</imagebutton></td>
<tr>
```

that simply means, the td holding the imagebutton is never removed, its already there, and hence the space.

you should hide the td instead of hiding `imagebuttons`

so give id to your tds and runat="server" attribute. and grab them from  the codebehind and set their visible =false;

or do this:

```
  td1.Attributes.Add("class","hide"); //where td1 is the id of a td
```

where `.hide` is a css class in your stylesheet or designer like this:

```
.hide
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanx but i have tried that also. its still showing the odd spaces

Comment: try adding css class to your tds to be hidden from codebehind instead of doing visible:false

Comment: and if the problem still presists, that simply means, your tr and td have fixed width, and hence, when you remove some of the tds, other tds adjust to share the space equally, but they don't expand themselves to fill the space. try giving your tds percentage width